# Is it possible to repeat an iteration of a loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have defined a for loop as follows which scans through a file made up of two columns, when it finds the keyword `DEFINE_MENU` the second column on this line refers to the title for a screen. The next instance of the keyword will define a title for a seperate screen and so on to the nth screen. At the moment the code is capable of defining the first menu title.

Is it possible, when I reach the second instance of the keyword `DEFINE_MENU` to repeat the loop for the same line, setting the `title_flag = 0` thereby repeating itself, capturing the second menu title?

```
def getInfo():

    title_flag = 0
    number = 1
    menus = {}
    items = {}
    title = None
    file = open('some_file', 'r')
    for line in file:
        # Test for comments, if they exist pass and move on
        if line[0] == '#':
            continue
        # Hop over blank lines
        if re.search(r'^\s+$', line):
            continue
        # Find the line where the title is defined
        if re.search('DEFINE_MENU', line) and title_flag == 0:
            type, name = line.split()
            title = name
            title_flag = 1
            continue
        # If DEFINE_MENU is found and flag has been raised, this
        # signifies a new menu definition so break.
        if re.search('DEFINE_MENU', line) and title_flag == 1:
            break
        if re.search('PRIV', line):
            (type, name, priv_holder, *description) = line.split()
        else:
            (type, name, *description) = line.split()
        # If flag has been raised, the line must follow the definition
        # of the menu, it must contains info regarding a menu item.
        if title_flag == 1:
            description = ' '.join(description)
            items[str(number)] = name
            number += 1
    file.close()
    menus[title] = items
    return menus
```

Thank you for your input!

Tom

**EDIT:** First, apologies for the confusion caused. Perhaps I thought of the problem as being simpler than I thought and gave less information than required. I will delve deeper, the input file i am using is of the form:

```
# MENU TYPE     NAME            PRIV?   DESCRIPTION
DEFINE_MENU     CRAGINS
MENU            menu_name1              This takes you to menu 1
MENU            menu_name2              This takes you to menu 2
VARIABLE        var_name1               Alter variable1
VARIABLE        var_name2       PRIV    Alter variable1
COMMAND         command1                Perform command1
DEFINE_MENU     MENU2
MENU            menu_name3              This takes you to menu 3
MENU            menu_name4              This takes you to menu 4
VARIABLE        var_name3               Alter variable3
VARIABLE        var_name4       PRIV    Alter variable4
COMMAND         command3                Perform command3
```

I had raised the flag as I further manipulate the data between the `DEFINE_MENU` calls. I have edited the code to include the full method that I have written.

The outcome is currently a dictionary where the key is the menu title and value is the another dictionary containing the menu items (values following the title) as follows:

```
{'title1': {'1': 'menu_name1', '3': 'var_name1', '2': 'menu_name2', '5': 'command1', '4': 'var_name2'}}
```

What I would like to have is a larger dictionary containing the menu titles as keys with the lowest level dictionary as the value. I understand that this is complicated so I'm sorry if it unclear, let me know if more information is required.

Thanks again

Tom

Comment: Why do you have different cases for `title_flag == 0` and `title_flag == 1`? Why do you even need `title_flag`?

Comment: Try formatting your question like this: _"I have input like this: ..."_  and _"I want my output to look like this: ..."_, and it's always nice to add a _"because..."_ and a _"here's what I have so far..."_.  Everyone here seems to be guessing :)

Comment: This kind of questions ask for use-cases: I have input A and I want ouput X, I have input B and...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem description correctly, you want to repeat the loop **body** (in certain cases) rather than "the iteration".  If that's the case, one workable approach is to make the loop body into a possibly-recursive function, returning `True` if the loop is to break, `False` if it is to continue, as well as the possible title.  For example, a most-direct (though probably not maximally elegant) function:

```
def body(line):
    global title_flag

    # skip over comments
    if line[0] == '#':
        return None, False
    # skip over blank lines
    if re.search(r'^\s+$', line):
        return None, False

    # Find the line where the title is defined
    if 'DEFINE_MENU' in line and title_flag == 0:
        type, name = line.split()
        title = name
        title_flag = 1
        return title, body(line)

    # If DEFINE_MENU is found and flag has been raised, this
    # signifies a new menu definition.
    if 'DEFINE_MENU' in line and title_flag == 1:
        return None, True
```

and the main-line code becomes:

```
title_flag = 0

with open('some_file', 'r') as afile:
    for line in afile:
        thetitle, mustbreak = body(line)
        if thetitle is not Note: title = thetitle
        if mustbreak: break
```

BTW: do **not** name your own variables by usurping built-in names like `file` -- that's a separate subject;-).  BTW2: I'm using `with` (assuming Python 2.6 or better, or 2.5 with an "import from the future") only because it's *the* right way to open and close a file;-). BTW3: I removed the `re.search` because it's wanton, inexplicable overkill when a simple `in` operator clearly does the same job.

I'm posting this code mostly to check in a concrete way whether I understood your specs, because, behavior-wise, this is definitely overkill -- there's no need (from the code you posted) to repeat the checks for comments and empty lines, nor the search for `'DEFINE_MENU"`, etc... you could just exit as soon as you've set the title (and `body` could then become inline code again).

But, I imagine that you have a reason for posting your question, i.e., that the simple behavior this has (and which could be had much more simply) is not optimal for you -- maybe by seeing the solution to your literal question you can point out what you want different than this, and then we can *actually* help you;-).

Comment: Thankyou for your response, although it did not directly solve my problem, it pointed me in the right direction and has provided me with some better coding techniques, namely using `in` rather than regex and I have renamed `file` to a non-built-in name. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this somewhat capture your logic?

```
menus = []
current_menu = None
for line in file:
    # ...
    # Find the line where the title is defined
    if re.search('DEFINE_MENU', line):
        if not current_menu is None:
            menus.append(current_menu)
        current_menu = Menu()
        type, name = line.split()
        current_menu.setTitle(name)
        continue
```

`Menu` would be a helper class for storing all the information that belongs to one menu. Also, since it seems all your cases are mutually exclusive, consider using `elif` instead of `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but would it be possible to just store your titles in a list?

```
titles = []

for line in infile: # don't shadow "file" keyword...

    if "DEFINE_MENU" in line:
        titles.append(line.split()[-1]) # append the last item
```

if you only want the first two titles, you could add an extra test:

```
if len(titles) == 2: break
```